# how to import external javascript in Mirth connect?

Tags: mirth

i am new to Mirth connect and i want to import extarnal javascript into my Mirth connect channel. i tried something like this while creating **channel** in **destination** and **Connector type: Javascript writer**.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://some-url/some-js.js"></script>
var obj = new OBbj-From-JS();
```

but i am getting exception as the **OBbj-From-JS() is not defined**.

need help to import the above JS.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In mirth, as per i know, you cannot import external javascript file, you have to write the code in destination transformer or source transformer, or one of 4 scripts.

by the way, in mirth , we can't use complete javascript as we use with `html` or `css`, if you want to use any java library then you have to download `jar` and you can add that jar in `custom-lib` and then from mirth you have to reload resources, which are in `setting>Resources`.

plus to use those library, in mirth import syntax are like this: 
`importPackage(java.util.*)`;

Comment: It is possible to use external JS file for any transformer step with "External Script" type. Then you specify which external file to use. And you are right, it will not load external libraries in the same way as it works for web.

Comment: yup, i never used that external script, because there's some syntax error, like if we have to use some method of library then in mirth we have to write full path like `Packages.com.net.sf.something something`, by the way thanks for informing about option. but if someone want to import external javascript, then they must have to write code as we write in `connector type: javascript` , am i right? @user3005941

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer a javascript file like that. But I have imported and referred  external javascript files inside transformer (either source/destination).

- Go to the transformer Right click and select add new step  In the
- right hand side select External Script
- Provide the reference js file directory along with the file name

Now you can create other steps and inherit the functions on that JS file.

[image]

I think this will work. But while writing a code Mirth will show errors as the referred javascript will be read only when you deploy the channel (at runtime)

Comment: thanks for your time, but i tried steps you mentioned and it didnt worked for me. can you please give me example of how to initialize the object once you give reference to your js in transformer. because i tried `var obj = new OBbj-From-JS();` and still getting same error.

Comment: Are you importing a JS library?. or just a custom JS written file?. 
In either case, make sure you create a externalscript as the first step, then try var obj = new OBbj-From-JS(); in next step. else create the object file also as an externalJS and give it a try. If you have it correctly and still the result is same. communicate me to vibinchander@outlook.com . I can help you out.